# Решил написать чат на jquery и столкнулся с ошибкой

Tags: jquery

Вообще я игрался с AJAX, но столкнулся с такой проблемой,(Убрал из кода ajax так как проблема не в нём) вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submit").on("click", function () {
var date = new Date();
var getText = $("#message").val(),
getTime = date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes();
var string = "<div id = 'deserve'><div id = 'name'><p>Игорь Велокеков</p></div><div id = 'message'>"+getText+"</div><div id = 'time'> "+getTime+"</div></div><br>";
$("#display").append(string);
})
})
```

И вот результат кода если несколько раз нажать на кнопку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот вопрос почему JQuery не обновляет переменную getText, а лепит как будто ничего и не вводили? (консоли молчат)

Вот HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Чат</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/display-style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container">




<div id = "display">

</div><br>

<textarea id="message" cols="50"  rows = "3" name="message"></textarea>  
<input style= "margin-left: 20px;" id="submit" type="button" value="Отправить" name="submit">
</div>
<div style="color:white;" class="result"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: потому что по нажатию кнопки "submit" перезагружается страница

Comment: Не вижу  **HTML**?

Comment: Я добавил HTML посмотрите!

Comment: Igor, моё упущение что я не добавил HTML код. Но там у меня просто стоит input type = button. И даже если бы поставил submit, то просто сбросил бы его preventDefault(e) через JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... <div id = 'message'> ...
```

и

```
<textarea id="message" ...
```

и

```
$("#message").val(),
```

Comment: ОООООООО ХОСПАДДЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕЕ:DD Спасибо

Comment: @АнтонТомаштик Пожалуйста ). Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Всё брат, от души - ты мне помог)